# Back stack is not getting cleared when navigating between activities using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I've two navigation graphs, one for `login/sign-up(login_nav_graph)` screens and one for `home(home_nav_graph)` screens. Each navigation graph has one `activity` and couple of `fragments`.

First I'm launching `home_nav_graph`, and checking if the user logged in or not. If the user not logged-in, I'm navigating to the `login_nav_graph` using its activity as the destination. And once the user is logged in successfully, I'm navigating to the `home_nav_graph` using the activity inside this graph as the destination.

Problem: When I navigate between these two navigation graphs, the back stack is not getting cleared. When I press the back button in `login_nav_graph` it's taking back to the screens in `home_nav_graph`.
I've already used the action elements like `popUpTo`, `popToInclusive` when navigating to the other graph but still back stack is not getting cleared.

Navigation component version I'm using: `2.3.0-alpha06`

**Update:**

This is the sample project I've created to reproduce the issue - [test-navigation](https://github.com/rajesh-esaver/test-navigation).

Also, created an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156179883) for this problem.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762919/android-navigation-editor-finish-activity

Comment: @lwilber `clearTask` attribute not present in my current navigation setup, may it's available in the older version